# Wordpress: No links in search results

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

is that putting something in the blog search wordpress I get search results but I can not enter, no link on the search titles. My template is Blank Theme. If I extract some code gladly publish it takes. Thank you friends.

Comment: You need to change you search.php file so that the h2 links to the post. Also is it called blank theme or blank slate.

Comment: I'll try, I'll tell you now : D